# Compiling an Angular app to be used as a partial view in a PHP framework

Tags: angular

I am working with **Angular 16.2.12**

I want my entire compiled app to be loaded in as a partial view included inside of a website made with a PHP framework. It's a page inside of a control panel, but the header and navigation of that system are outside of Angular because most of the rest of it is not Angular-based.

In **angular.json** I know that I can change the input file and the output path here:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
```

I can rename index.html and edit the index file itself.

I only really want the compiled scripts and css, and the `<app-root></app-root>` tag. I can't have tags like `<html>` or `<body>` because it's a partial view. And I don't want to use iFrames.

The problem is that if I remove most of the src page's HTML, and in particular if I remove the `<html>` tag then `ng build` returns an error:

```
✖ Index html generation failed.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')
```

Looking at the compiled output *with* the  tag I can see it adds an attribute here `<html lang="en" data-critters-container>` so presumably this is required.

What's the recommended way of solving this? Is it *only* intended to be compiled as a self contained complete app?

I'm essentially wanting individual page widgets (with no Angular routing) and with navigation being outside of Angular.

**Additional note**

I realise I could just manually copy the `<app-root></app-root>` and script tags into my PHP views, but each time the Angular app code changes the filenames change because of **outputHashing**. And I realise I could turn off outputHashing but it's actually extremely useful since we use aggressive server side caching and need filenames to change with each deploy. So it would be great to leave that switched on. But I can't find a mechanism to fetch those tags with each build and put them into a partial view that I can use.

Maybe an `<iframe>` is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's being caused by the inlining for styling.

In your angular.json, instead of "optimization": true, use

```
"optimization": {
   "scripts": true,
   "fonts": true,
   "styles": {
       "minify": true,
       "inlineCritical": false
   }
}
```

inlineCritical false disables the logic that tries to make the first paint CSS faster, but that won't be useful in your case anyway.

Comment: Bug post for this issue can be found here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26906